# How to store ASP.NET masterpage data in application cache for set duration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I've been reading '[ASP.NET-MVC Tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/passing-data-to-view-master-pages-cs)' to learn how to generate data for the 'masterpage' view in an ASP.NET MVC application.  It suggests the pattern of using a 'base-controller' and generating the data in its constructor.

My issue is that I wish to store the application data in the application cache rather than the viewdata dictionary.  The application cache doesn't exist in the controller constructors as its set later, how can I store data for the masterpage view in application cache?

Comment: what is the application cache in the controller? first I've heard of it..

Comment: @Ahmad It's the normal ASP.NET Web Cache. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412868/how-to-store-asp-net-masterpage-data-in-application-cache-for-set-duration/3413495#3413495

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Well.... a version that works.  I needed to add the applciation data to the cache when the ControllerActionInvoker's 'InvokeAction' method fires.  To do this I had to create a new ActionInvoker as below.

```
public class ContextActionInvoker : ControllerActionInvoker
{
    public const string testMessageCacheAndViewDataKey = "TESTMESSAGE";
    private const int testListLifetimeInMinutes = 10;

    public ContextActionInvoker(ControllerContext controllerContext) : base() { }

    public override bool InvokeAction(ControllerContext context, string actionName)
    {
        // Cache a test list if not already done so
        var list = context.HttpContext.Cache[testMessageCacheAndViewDataKey];
        if (list == null)
        {
            list = new SelectList(new[] {
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Text 10", Value = "10" },
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Text 15", Value = "15", Selected = true },
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Text 25", Value = "25" },
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Text 50", Value = "50" },
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Text 100", Value = "100" },
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Text 1000", Value = "1000" }
            }, "Value", "Text");
            context.HttpContext.Cache.Insert(testMessageCacheAndViewDataKey, list, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(testListLifetimeInMinutes), TimeSpan.Zero);
        }
        context.Controller.ViewData[testMessageCacheAndViewDataKey] = list;

        return base.InvokeAction(context, actionName);
    }
}
```

Once this was done I needed to create a custom controllerfactory that would make sure the correct ActionInvoker method was called. I did this by doing...

```
public class ContextControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        IController controller = base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
        Controller contextController = controller as Controller;

        if (contextController != null)
        {
            var context = new ControllerContext(requestContext, contextController);
            contextController.ActionInvoker = new ContextActionInvoker(context);
        }
        return controller;
    }
}
```

I then had to tell the MVC application which controllerfactory to use. I did this by changing Global.asax.cs a bit...

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    ...

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(typeof(ContextControllerFactory));
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Then on the masterpage I used the dropdownlist HTML helper method, by doing...

```
<%: Html.DropDownList(MVC_MasterPage_data_set_in_cache.Controllers.ContextActionInvoker.testMessageCacheAndViewDataKey) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you override the `Initialize` method in your base controller, you have access to the `Cache`. `Initialize` will execute before any action is executed on any request for an action in the controller.

```
protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
{
    base.Initialize(requestContext);
    var list = requestContext.HttpContext.Cache[testMessageCacheAndViewDataKey];
    if (list == null) { ... }
}
```